# tensorflow 2.10 keras fit fails to use GPU

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, tf.keras

I habe been running an image classifier with tensorfloe and keras in python3.8 on windows10 and upgraded tensorflow from 2.8.3 to 2.10 which selects GPU by default.
When mode.fit begins the first epoch, it abruptly quits the program with no message.
Looking at reports of this type of failure, I have tried reducing batch size to 16 and reducing my
augmentation to a bare minimum, but the failure persists.
And if I restart from a checkpoint for model.evaluate, this also quits with no message.
Here is stripped-down code which exhibits the problem:

```
import numpy as np
import sys, os, pathlib, glob
import cv2, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
    
print(tf.__version__,' only 2.10.0 supports GPU on windows')     
# tf.config.set_visible_devices([], 'CPU') # hide the CPU
# tf.config.set_visible_devices(gpus[0], 'GPU') # unhide potentially hidden GPU
print(tf.config.get_visible_devices())
#  tf.keras models if GPU available will by default run on a single GPU
from tensorflow.python import keras # and from this keras:-
print(keras.__version__)
from keras import models, optimizers, layers, regularizers
'''
Download  3,670  photos of flowers. contains five class sub-directories
dataset_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz"
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file(origin=dataset_url, fname='flower_photos', untar=True)
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)
'''
epochs     = 50 
batch_size = 16
learn_rate = .1 
metric     = 'accuracy'
opt        = 'RMSprop'
img_height = 180
img_width  = 180

data_dir = "./ImageData/flowers" # or plankton, catsVSdogs, vegetables,&c &c
train_dir = data_dir + '/train'   # train and test subdirectories
imagenames = list(glob.glob(train_dir + '/*/*.jpg', recursive=True))
num_classes = len(os.listdir(train_dir))

split= .2
train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  train_dir,
  validation_split=split,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

val_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  train_dir,
  validation_split=split,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

data_augmentation = tf.keras.Sequential(
     [layers.RandomRotation((-0.5,.5)),
      layers.RandomZoom((-0.2,.2)),
      layers.RandomBrightness((-0.75,.75)), 
      layers.RandomContrast(0.2)
      ] )
# Configure the dataset for performance
AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE
train_ds = train_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds   =   val_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
print('train, val sizes:',len(train_ds), len(val_ds),'Optimizer:', opt)
# By default, if a CPU and a GPU, the priority is GPU in TensorFlow.
with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
      data_augmentation,
      tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255), # normalize RGB data [0, 255] to [0, 1] range
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3,  activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),        
      tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),   # cos flowers overfitting
      tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes)
    ])
    model.compile(optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'],
                  loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True))
    model.build(input_shape = (batch_size, img_height, img_width, 3))
    model.summary()

    ckptfile = f'Checkpoint//flowersGPU_weights.h5'
    from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau, ModelCheckpoint
    earlystop = EarlyStopping(patience=10, verbose=1, monitor='accuracy', restore_best_weights=True)
    valstop   = EarlyStopping(patience=10, verbose=1, monitor='val_accuracy', restore_best_weights=True)
    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(ckptfile)        
    lred = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor=metric, patience=5, verbose=1, factor=.5, min_lr=0.00001)
    callbacks = [earlystop, valstop, checkpoint, lred]
    print(f'Fit model with early stopping {metric} epochs {epochs} checkpoint {ckptfile}')
    history = model.fit(train_ds, validation_data=val_ds, epochs=epochs,
                      callbacks=callbacks)     
    # visualising training and validation accuracy
    print(history.history.keys()) # as below:
    acc      = history.history['accuracy']
    val_acc  = history.history['val_accuracy']
    loss     = history.history['loss']
    val_loss = history.history['val_loss']
    lr       = history.history['lr']
    lrate = [100 * r for r in lr] # expand for plot
    epochs_range = len(acc)
    print(f' {epochs} epochs, stopped after {epochs_range}')
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
    plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
    plt.plot(epochs_range, acc, label='Training Accuracy')
    plt.plot(epochs_range, val_acc, label='Validation Accuracy')
    plt.legend(loc='lower right')
    plt.title('Training and Validation Accuracy')

    plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
    plt.plot(epochs_range,     loss, label='Training Loss')
    plt.plot(epochs_range, val_loss, label='Validation Loss')
    plt.plot(epochs_range,    lrate, label='Learning Rate')
    plt.legend(loc='upper right')
    plt.title('Training and Validation Loss')
    plt.show()
```

with tf.device('/device:CPU:0'): model.fit and evaluate again works as before.

Comment: Please add reproducible code.

Comment: Hi @ Nick, Please try again executing the code mentioned in this [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/RenuPatelGoogle/b2908d54b192af029ab0d17204f6bd9b/75879857.ipynb). Also check if tensorflow with GPU is properly configured by verify the given steps in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native).

Comment: Thanks for your input, where I see that moving to python3.19 might be helpful. Until I do that I am now using pytorch with GPU support.